# ¿Cómo puede mostrar archivos desde una ruta externa a mi proyecto de laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

necesito mostrar archivos pdf y jpg que se encuentran en

> /var/www/html/archivos/hola.pdf o hola.jpg

estoy utilizando lo siguiente:

```
<a href="{{asset('../var/www/html/hola.pdf')}}">Ver detalle</a>
```

y me muestra un error de NOT FOUNT...

¿cómo se puede hacer?

Comment: a que te refieres con "ruta externa a mi proyecto"?

Answer (score 0):

Para poder visualizar archivos se deben tener en cuenta dos puntos.

**Permisos de Archivos:** Lo primero antes de poder visualizar el archivo es que este tenga el permiso para mostrarse, puede verificar que tengas el permiso con `sudo chmod +r TUARCHIVO`.

**Rutas Relativa y/o Absoluta:** Lo segundo es que este atento muy bien a la ruta real del archivo, si usas el helper `asset()` esta se posicionara en `TU_PROYECTO/public`

## Posibles soluciones:

1. Ahora bien estas usando `../var/www/html/hola.pdf` lo que quiere decir que tiene tu proyecto fuera de la directorio `/var` , normalmente si tiene un proyecto laravel leste se encontrara en `/var/www/tu_proyecto` y para ver el archivo debe usar '../../html/hola.pdf' porque asset es relativo a `/var/www/tu_proyecto/public/` o `/var/www/tu_proyecto/asset/`.
2. Otra solución es poner ese archivo en tu carpeta `asset/pdf` y así poder verlo con `asset('pdf/hola.pdf')`

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probar